# How Can I arrange these files into Spring MVC structure

Tags: spring-mvc

Here is MainApp.java

```
package spring.pac;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = 
      (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");

      System.out.println("------Records Creation--------" );
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Zara", 11);
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Nuha", 2);
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Ayan", 15);

      System.out.println("------Listing Multiple Records--------" );
      List<Student> students = studentJDBCTemplate.listStudents();
      for (Student record : students) {
         System.out.print("ID : " + record.getId() );
         System.out.print(", Name : " + record.getName() );
         System.out.println(", Age : " + record.getAge());
      }

      System.out.println("----Updating Record with ID = 2 -----" );
      studentJDBCTemplate.update(2, 20);

      System.out.println("----Listing Record with ID = 2 -----" );
      Student student = studentJDBCTemplate.getStudent(2);
      System.out.print("ID : " + student.getId() );
      System.out.print(", Name : " + student.getName() );
      System.out.println(", Age : " + student.getAge());

   }
}
```

Student.java

```
package spring.pac;

public class Student {
private Integer age;
   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
}
```

StudentDAO.java

```
package spring.pac;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface StudentDAO {

   public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);

   public void create(String name, Integer age);

   public Student getStudent(Integer id);

   public List<Student> listStudents();

   public void delete(Integer id);

   public void update(Integer id, Integer age);
}
```

StudentJDBCTemplate.java

```
package spring.pac;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate {
 private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }

   public void create(String name, Integer age) {
      String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";

      jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
      System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
      return;
   }

   public Student getStudent(Integer id) {
      String SQL = "select * from Student where id = ?";
      Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
                        new Object[]{id}, new StudentMapper());
      return student;
   }

   public List<Student> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student";
      List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
                                new StudentMapper());
      return students;
   }

   public void delete(Integer id){
      String SQL = "delete from Student where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
      System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }

   public void update(Integer id, Integer age){
      String SQL = "update Student set age = ? where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, age, id);
      System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }
}
```

StudentMapper.java

```
package spring.pac;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class StudentMapper implements RowMapper<Student> {

      public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

          Student student = new Student();

          student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));

          student.setName(rs.getString("name"));

          student.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));

          return student;
   }
}
```

I am using JBoss 5 and eclipse. Please help me  which one is Model, which one is View and which one is Controller

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this isn't a spring MVC project.
To comply with Spring MVC you should have a Controller class annotated with @Controller. Moreover, I can't see any jsp page or similar which can act as a view.

Just to summarize spring MVC elements:

**controller:**
 it is a component which receives the http requests and triggers corresponding business logic.

**model:**
 it is nothing but a bunch of data representing the domainobject passed to the view

**view:**
 the way data are redered.

Here you have an example to help you to get the concept. Let's suppose you have a web application which allow you to search for a student in a database. By enetring the student name and hitting the "search" button you send an http request (probably a POST) to the server and wait for a response. So, the web application has a **controller** class, for example  `StudentsController` which manages requests about students. The `StudentsController` expose a method searchStudent(...) which is bound to the URL `http://.../student/search`. It means that when you send a request to this URL, the method is executed.
Ok, let's suppose that you passed in the request body the needed parameters to retrieve the student by name. Inside the `searchStudent(...)` method there happen some business logic to retrieve the student from the db. Probably the information fetched in this way will be represented as a `Student` object you want to send to the client as an html page.

To do so, you will send the Student to a jsp which format the data from the Student class inside some html tags. Here the Student class passed to the jsp is the **model**, and the jsp itself is the **view**.

You could also send the student data in json format, to some client. The json representation of the student is also a view.

Comment: without using Spring MVC can it possible to render the values in view using these classes. please tell me the detail process..

Comment: no. StudentMapper, StudentJDBCTemplate and StudentDAO are about persistence. Student is the domain object and the main does nothing but interacting with the db, first creating three students and then fetching them and printing their attributes. There is **NO SERVER** here. **no MVC at all**.